# Angular only show elements of array which respect a certain condition with *ngIf?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, element, angular-ng-if

I'm using material table to display my array. I want an option for the user so when he ticks "daily", it only shows the files where the file_name's 5th last character is equal to "D", and "M" for monthly ones.

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!-- Unit Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="unit">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Unit</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"  *ngIf=" file_name.charAt(((apiDataFile.file_name).length) - 5) == 'M'"> {{element.unit}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- File Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="file_name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> File Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" *ngIf=" file_name.charAt(((apiDataFile.file_name).length) - 5) == 'M'"> {{element.file_name}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
        [ngClass]="{highlighted: selectedRowIndex == row.id}"  (click)="highlight(row)" >
    </tr>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[20, 5, 10, 50, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

</div>
```

In my example I want to only print the monthly files, which means that the 5th character from the end is equal to "M", without the tick option.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: See how they have implemented the filter here. https://stackblitz.com/angular/dkgnnevebag?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts

Comment: Yes I'm already using this filter, and I have a filter for each column in my application. What I'm trying to achieve is more like just a condition which will only display the monthly or daily files based on the file name.

Comment: post this method code  file_name.charAt(((apiDataFile.file_name) as well

Comment: hello, well the `file_name.charAt(((apiDataFile.file_name).length) - 5)` just returns the 5th character from the end of the file name, but i don't know where to put the *ngif, and theres already the *matCellDef so I can't put another directive

Comment: You will need to find a way to filter the datasource. NgIf on mat-cell will resolve nothing for you.